# Python 3.3 installation on 64-bit windows 8.1

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use Scikit using Python 3.3 on 64-bit Windows 8.1. I installed Python 3.3 from the site below:

```
           http://www.oldapps.com/Python.php?old_python=12256?download
```

Also, Scikit was installed from the site below (being mindful to pick up 64-bit amd version that works with py3.3). 
               http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn

However, I find that the SVM grid_search hangs for ever. On debugging, I find that the "Parallel()" routine (part of parallel.py) never returns.

My program was running alright on lower version of python 2.7.4.

Could this be installation error?

Answer (score 0):

This is in the interest of the greater Python developers. All these problems arose as I was using google's PyScripter. It is a highly unstable Python IDE. Soon after I shifted to PyCharm, the entire codebase without any change started running like a charm.